# Making URLs Standardized

Tags: perl

I have looked all over for ways in Perl to make URLs standardized. In other words, I'm trying to find a way to check and then change the URL forms example.org, www.example.org or http://example.org to the standard form http://www.example.org, no matter what the domain name. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Neither http:// nor www is standard across all websites. Take `http://perldoc.perl.org`, for example. But this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Please use the reserved names like example.com and example.org and don't use domain names you don't own. Apart from that `http://example.org` and `http://www.example.org` etc can be different servers and sometimes they are actually different. And yes, it looks like an XY problem.

Comment: [no-www](http://no-www.org/) might be useful.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a standard, I'm saying I want to standardize it in my list. It doesn't matter if it's all www.example.org, all http://www.example.org or all http:// example.org, I just want to make them all the same, As I said, I'm a beginner in perl and the code I made sorta works but is lame and I'm looking for maybe better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just normalize it yourself as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $host = 'example.org';
my $canonical = 'http://www.example.org';

for ( 'example.org',
      'www.example.org',
      'http://example.org',
      'example.org/foo/bar?baz=123',
      'www.example.org/foo/bar?baz=123',
      'http://example.org/foo/bar?baz=123',
    ) {

    # Anything followed by 'example.org' followed by anything
    my ($path) = m|^.*?$host(.*)$|;
    my $canonical_path = join '', $canonical, $path || '';
    print sprintf("% 40s => %s\n", $_, $canonical_path);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
                       example.org => http://www.example.org
                   www.example.org => http://www.example.org
                http://example.org => http://www.example.org
       example.org/foo/bar?baz=123 => http://www.example.org/foo/bar?baz=123
   www.example.org/foo/bar?baz=123 => http://www.example.org/foo/bar?baz=123
http://example.org/foo/bar?baz=123 => http://www.example.org/foo/bar?baz=123
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the below in `.htaccess` file of each website.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect (301) non-www domain to www.